# C# - Instance container vs. no container in an evaluation loop that is run intensely

Tags: c#, loops, optimization, real-time

In C#, I have an evaluation loop that is run very intensely (for a real-time application). I am wondering whether I should:

- A) simply initialize the parameters outside the loop and pass them as argument to an evaluation function;
- B) instanciate an object (a container) for calling the evaluation function and cache the parameters.

Does it make any difference in terms of efficiency / memory / garbage collection?

Code A:

```cs
Parameters parameters = new Parameters(); // An external constructor
while (true)
{
    Evaluate(parameters);
}
```

Code B:

```cs
public class Container
{
    private Parameters parameters;
    
    public Container()
    {
        parameters = new Parameters(); // An external constructor
    }

    public void Evaluate()
    {
        Evaluate(parameters);
    }
}
```

```cs
Container container = new();
while (true)
{
    container.Evaluate();
}
```

Comment: Why not try both and measure ?

Comment: ^^ => [BenchmarkDotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)

Comment: _"for a **real-time** application"_ - That's probably the colloquial usage of "real-time", meaning "as fast as possible", _right_?

Comment: Now, if this construct is suspicious to you before even having started, maybe think about if that's the way to go to begin with? Can you invert the responsibility and push instead of poll (in a tight loop, which in itself is an anti-ish pattern)?

Comment: For GC, though: no difference. Both codes create exactly 1 instance of `Parameters` that lives _at least_ as long as the loop keeps looping. The only overhead would be in the `Container` instance (of which there's also only 1 - which is probably neglectable.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make any difference in terms of efficiency / memory / garbage collection?

With a single parameter, no. Your two examples should be close to identical.

If you have lots of parameters it may make some small difference if you put them in a parameter object or not, i.e. `Evaluate(p1, p2, p3, ...)` vs `Evaluate(parameters)`, where `parameters` contains p1, p2, p3, etc.

Do keep in mind that the difference will be measured in nano-seconds. Chances are that you have more significant bottlenecks. I would recommend doing some profiling to get a better idea about what actually takes time. And if you have an idea for a optimization, use [benchmark .net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) to measure performance before and after to confirm that you actually made an improvement.

Note that "Real time" might mean everything between "Update a billboard every 15 minutes" to "Check if brakes has locked up every 100us", and these extremes will require completely different approaches. So you should be much more specific when talking about your performance requirement, preferably including actual numbers.